# Copy files from single source to multiple destinations

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I have a script to copy files from local machine to Azure blob, but my new requirement is to copy half of source files into one blob container and another half into another blob container. Let me know if I can do so using parallel or one after the other. I am using `azcopy` for now to move these files without splitting and from only one source to one destination.

```
.\AzCopy.exe /Source:$localfilepath /Dest:$Destinationpath /DestKey:$key1 /S
```

Comment: you might be able to use `start-job` to run more than one at a time

Comment: iterate thru the collection, test to see if `$index % 2` is zero, use that to select target1 or target2.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, if there is a pattern for filtering these file names, you can use the parameter `Pattern` of `AzCopy` tool to separately upload them in two times, such as the command as below from the section [`Upload blobs matching a specific pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#upload-blobs-matching-a-specific-pattern) of the offical tutorial if they are named with the `a` prefix.

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /DestKey:key /Pattern:a* /S
```

Here is the description of the parameter [`Pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#patternfile-pattern) of AzCopy

> **/Pattern:"file-pattern"**
>
> Specifies a file pattern that indicates which files to copy. The behavior of the /Pattern parameter is determined by the location of the source data, and the presence of the recursive mode option. Recursive mode is specified via option /S.
>
> If the specified source is a directory in the file system, then standard wildcards are in effect, and the file pattern provided is matched against files within the directory. If option /S is specified, then AzCopy also matches the specified pattern against all files in any subfolders beneath the directory.
>
> If the specified source is a blob container or virtual directory, then wildcards are not applied. If option /S is specified, then AzCopy interprets the specified file pattern as a blob prefix. If option /S is not specified, then AzCopy matches the file pattern against exact blob names.
>
> If the specified source is an Azure file share, then you must either specify the exact file name, (e.g. abc.txt) to copy a single file, or specify option /S to copy all files in the share recursively. Attempting to specify both a file pattern and option /S together results in an error.
>
> AzCopy uses case-sensitive matching when the /Source is a blob container or blob virtual directory, and uses case-insensitive matching in all the other cases.
>
> The default file pattern used when no file pattern is specified is . for a file system location or an empty prefix for an Azure Storage location. Specifying multiple file patterns is not supported.
>
> Applicable to: Blobs, Files

If there is a simple pattern for files, you have to manually move them into the directories of their own category or write a simple script to filter them to generate the command strings for uploading. Then you can use [`Foreach-Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1) in PowerShell to realize the parallel upload workflow to satisfy your needs.